# How do I query for a field with a single quote or apostrophe? e.g. "CROHN'S DISEASE"

Tags: openfda, api

I want to list all drugs that have "CROHN'S DISEASE" or "CROHN^S DISEASE" as `drugindication`:

```
http://api.fda.gov/drug/event.json?search=patient.drug.drugindication.exact:%22CROHN'S+DISEASE%22&count=patient.drug.openfda.brand_name.exact&limit=100
```

If you list Humira's drug indications

```
http://api.fda.gov/drug/event.json?search=patient.drug.openfda.brand_name.exact:%22HUMIRA%22&count=patient.drug.drugindication.exact&limit=100
```

Crohn's Disease shows up as a very common drug indication for Humira. Now I want to find other drugs that also have Crohn's Disease as a `drugindication`. How should I query for this? I don't believe it is currently possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, in your Humira drug indications response, there is some data quality *idiosyncracies* because I see `"CROHN'S DISEASE"` and `CROHN^S DISEASE` as possible values of `patient.drug.drugindication.exact`.

Unfortunately, this has been a known issue since 2014 (at https://github.com/FDA/openfda/issues/29) and there isn't a fix just yet.

For the time being, you could do a fuzzy-ish search like the following:

```
http://api.fda.gov/drug/event.json?search=patient.drug.drugindication:%22CROHN%22
```

which should match both of the permutations of Crohn's disease above.

Comment: I know this is an old thread, but I have a question... The OP is requesting all drugs that are indicated for Crohn's, but when you use the URL in this answer, I don't believe you get a complete list of drugs that are indicated for Crohn's. For example, Remicade and Cimzia are not returned in the result set. Any ideas why?